# Haskell Last generator in do {...} must be an expression error typed binding error

Tags: haskell

Im doing a small system from Haskell and im getting two errors called 
"**Last generator in do {...} must be an expression**" and 
"**Type error in explicitly typed binding
Term           : (fname,lname,cnic)
Type           : (a,b,c)
Does not match : Database**"

im new to haskell so plz help me out.

```
-------Data types-------

type FirstName = String
type LastName = String
type CustomerNIC = String
type Database = ( FirstName , LastName , CustomerNIC ) 
--type Details = [Database]

------Data base---------


exampleBase :: [Database]
exampleBase = [ ( "Kevin" , "Desilva" , "8929323V" ),( "Nimal" , "Perera" , "89120323V" ) ]

-------Main Menu-----------------------------
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = do line <- getline 
        return (read line :: Int)

selectsearch ::IO()
selectsearch = do 
                    putStr"\n\n\t 1.Search by NIC:"
                    putStr"\n\n\t 2.Search by First Name:"
                    putStr"\n\n\t Your Chocie:"
                    input<-getInt
                    subsearch input

subsearch :: Int->IO()
subsearch x = do
                if(x=1) then do
                                putStr"\n\t Enter NIC:"
                                cnic <- getLine
                                subsearch
                else if (x=2) then do
                                putStr"\n\t Enter First Name:"
                                cnic <- getLine
                                subsearch
                else if (x=3) then putStr "\n ERROR"
                                selectsearch

            else MainMenu

------- Search ------------

getfName :: Database -> FirstName 
getfName ( fname , lname , cnic ) = fname

searchByFirstName :: Database -> FirstName -> Database
searchByFirstName (a:ax) fname 
                    | fname == getfName a = a 
                    | length ax == 0 && getfName a/= fname = ("No Data","",0)
                    | otherwise = searchByFirstName ax fname
```

Comment: Always tell us which lines the error messages refer to.

Comment: And which lines are those? Code listings on this website aren't automatically numbered. It's usually best to add comments in your code sample to indicate where the errors are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- There are weird indentation things throughout.  Make sure you're using spaces and not tabs.
- In `subsearch`, you often have `cnic <- getLine` (when you probably want `getInt`), but then not use that in the recursive call.
- In your `if` statements, you should have `x == 1`, etc. rather than `x = 1`.  Also consider using a case statement or guards rather than nested if-then-else.
- You're missing a "do" in your `x == 3` case.
- `getInt` is identical to `readLn`.
- Your `searchByFirstName` function could be written better.
- A `Database` is made of three `String` fields, but your error case in `searchByFirstName` returns a value of type `(String, String, Int)`.

Comment: Thanx for your comment...it helped me up-to some extend